# How exactly does git branching and merging work for development and deployment?

Tags: git

I understand the concepts of branching and merging in git. But I am confused how exactly the commits get merged into another branch. For ex: if I have used CDN for bootstrap in deploying and static files for development, then if I make changes in my development environment and merge those commits to deployment branch, will it replace the links(CDN with static)? And similar other changes. Please explain.

Comment: git will only merge changes in your code, so, unless you replaced your actual source code and modified the links - they will not change; but if you have, they will. git is not the ideal tool to separate and manage settings for development vs. deployment environments.

Comment: Will following links be helpful to you? https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-merge  https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows

Comment: @BurhanKhalid So you mean only the last commit (changes) will reflect in the merge? What will be the ideal tool to separate and manage settings for development vs deployment environments? How should I manage both?

Comment: https://12factor.net/